# spring boot & swagger/openapi

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I recently upgraded my Spring Boot app from 2.1 to 2.5. Since then, I am struggling to use Swagger/OpenAPI.  I see two issues:

when I navigate to http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html or http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/api-docs/ I get a message:
*No API definition provided.*

I am getting CORS errors on Swagger calls (browser and postman work fine), which I think is due to the call being http instead of https.  The configuration seems quite a bit different but here is what I have:

**Config**:

```java
@Configuration
@CrossOrigin
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT","DELETE");
    }
}
```

**application.yml**:

```yaml
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger.html
    operationsSorter: method
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
```

**relevant gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'idea'
    id 'application'
}
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-data-rest:1.5.11'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.4'
```

When I use Swagger to make a call I get the error about http vs https:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried without `@CrossOrigin` in `WebConfig`?

Comment: yes, Swagger still defaults to http instead of https

Comment: @JoãoDias do you know the settings to make it default to https, assuming that helps with the CORS issue?

Comment: What happens when you use https in the browser instead? Does it work properly?

Comment: the swagger is running on a https website.  The server dropdown only shows http, as do all the "Try It" button.

Comment: @JoãoDias does any of this make sense - why the default call is http instead of https?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1670 and https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1006. Maybe you can find there something useful.

Comment: thank you for the pointer, unfortunately they didn't contain an answer for me.